# How to access constants defined in java interface from kotlin interface

Tags: java, kotlin

Why accessing constants defined in java interface from kotlin interface is not allowed or at least I am not able to access it. Is there any other way?

(Yes,I know The constant interface pattern is a poor use of interfaces from Effective Java book)

Following code (java) compiles

```java
// ==== JSubsystem.java ====

public interface JSubsystem {
    String IRIS = "IRIS";
    String TCS = "TCS";
    // ...
}

// ==== JComponentType.java ====
public interface JComponentType {
    String HCD = "HCD";
    String Assembly = "Assembly";
    // ...
}

interface Demo extends JSubsystem {
    default void foo() {
        System.out.println(IRIS);
    }
}
```

But in the following kotlin interface which extends from java, IRIS|TCS|HCD is not accessible

```
// ==== AllModels.kt ====

interface AllModels : JSubsystem, JComponentType {
    fun foo() = println(IRIS)
}
```

More context on why we ended up at this situation:

We have  a large `scala` codebase, all the models provide `java` and `scala` access.

Now we have scripting requirement for *1-5%* of our users where we have utilised kotlin's scripting (.kts), dsl, coroutines and suspension features

We have provided `script` construct inside which users will have access to complete DSL and all the models.

We do not want users to explicitly import models from different files and we do not want to repeat defining models again in kotlin.

One of the solution we thought could work in this case is having java models (these are simple delegations to scala models) in interface and then have one interface at kotlin side which extends from all these java model interfaces and then `script` can be `receiver` of this interface - `AllModels`

Comment: `println(JSubsystem.IRIS)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize your script environment as described in https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/scripting-support.md, in particular you can add imports which will be automatically available with [`defaultImports`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/c7e9a6c5d9046afc4074548d3d0f1496c4194efa/libraries/scripting/common/src/kotlin/script/experimental/api/scriptCompilation.kt#L112).

[This example](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/make-auto-completion-work-in-kotlin-scripts-with-context/10185/5) in the Kotlin discussion forum should be helpful:

> First, you need to create a script definition - a separate jar that describes your script “template”, e.g. similar to the https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-main-kts
>   Your definition may look something like:
>
> ```
> @KotlinScript(fileExtension = "custom.ext", compilationConfiguration = ScriptConfiguration::class)
> abstract class MyScript(val bindings: Map<String, Any?>) {
>     val ortResult = bindings["ortResult"] as OrtResult
>     val evalErrors = mutableListOf<OrtIssue>()
> }
>
> object ScriptConfiguration : ScriptCompilationConfiguration(
>     {
>         defaultImports("com.here.ort.model.*", "java.util.*")
>         ide {
>             acceptedLocations(ScriptAcceptedLocation.Everywhere)
>         }
>     })
> ```
>
> It is a good idea to have a dedicated extension for your scripts (“custom.ext” in the example above), since IDE distinguish scripts by the extension.
>
> Then you’ll need to create your own JSR-223 factory the same way as here - https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-script-util/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/script/jsr223/KotlinJsr223ScriptEngineFactoryExamples.kt#L28, but use your script definition (MyScript) in place of KotlinStandardJsr223ScriptTemplate. You probably can do it in the same jar. And you need to register it in the services folder, of course.
>
> You’ll still need a postface part in your evaluator though, but it seems not relevant to the IDE.
>
> Then finally you need to supply Intellij with the definition. The simplest ad-hoc way to do it is to specify the FQN of your definition class along with the classpath needed to load it in the kotlin compiler settings -> “Kotlin scripting” in Intellij.

Comment: Thank you, In the end I went through this repo https://github.com/bamboo/kotlinconf2019 which satisfied my requirement

Comment: If it was sufficient, perhaps you should accept the answer?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify interface explicitly:

`fun foo() = println(JSubsystem.IRIS)`

Or you can import constant explicitly:

`import your.package.name.JSubsystem.IRIS`

Comment: As per the context provided in original post,

We do not want users to explicitly import models from different files and we do not want to repeat defining models again in kotlin.

This is in context of kotlin's `script` support.
IRIS, TCS etc should be directly available in `script` without any import

Comment: @PritamKadam Can't do I suppose. Kotlin scripts are still Kotlin.

Comment: @xinaiz You can actually, see my answer.